# For any point $x$ in a Banach space $E$, there is $m$ in closed subspace $M$ st. $d(x,M)=d(x,m)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

What I have proved is: such point exists in a (more general) convex closed set if and only if $E$ is a reflexive Banach space (One direction is proved by weakly compact. Another direction is by James theorem).
In particular, such point is unique if $E$ is uniformly convex (we may call it a projection of $x$ on $M$). Could someone present a counterexample in a more general Banach space? I will appreciate it so much.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You just need a continuous functional $f$ which doesn't achieve its maximum on the ball, and $f^{-1}\{0\}$ will suffice.

Comment: @Theo Bendit, I got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested by   Theo Bendit,Consider the continuous linear from
$T:C[0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$,$T(f)=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(t)dt-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}f(t)dt$.it is easy to see that $\lvert \lvert T \rvert \rvert =1$ but there is no $f\in C[0,1]$ of norm 1 such that $T(f)=1$.Now consider the closed subspace $Ker(f)$ and let $g\in E\setminus Ker(f)$,then there is no $h\in Ker(f)$ such that $d(g,Ker(f))=d(g,h)$,if not ,define $x:=\frac{1}{\lvert \lvert g-h \rvert \rvert} (g-h)$,then $\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert =1$,and $\lvert T(x) \rvert=d(x,Ker(T))=1$,Contradiction !.

Comment: Thanks! It's an excellent example!

Answer (score 0):

Another example can be provided by $c_0,$ the sequences convergent to $0$ with norm $\|x\|=\sup_n|x_n|.$ Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {x_n\over 2^n}$$ The norm of this functional is equal $1.$ But there is no sequence in $c_0$ for which the norm is attained.

Another example, this time on $\ell^1.$ Let
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-2^{-n-1})x_n$$ The norm of the functional is equal $1,$ but there is no sequence $x\in \ell^1$ such that $\|x\|_1=1$ and $|f(x)|=1.$